# uwsgi & Django with port 80

Tags: django, uwsgi

If I run uwsgi with `uwsgi --ini kb_uwsgi.ini --http :80` it gives me an error:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from kb_uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.14 (64bit) on [Thu Jan 26 12:34:51 2017] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 06 January 2017 11:55:37
os: Linux-4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016
nodename: ip-172-31-16-133
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz
your processes number limit is 64137
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 769]
```

the site loads however if i preceed the command with `sudo` or use port `:8000` eg `uwsgi --ini kb_uwsgi.ini --http :8000`

Now I tried to make the site live with nginx and uwsgi I get `a 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)` nginx works okay because the favicon loads and I can access static files with `\static\...` I know this is Django having an issue rendering. I've tried also loading `uwsgi --ini kb_uwsgi.ini --http :8000` without loading the djangoenv and it still loads.

The `kb_uwsgi.ini` file looks like this:

```
# kb_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz
# Django's wsgi file
module          = kb.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /tmp/kb.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
# chmod-socket    = 664
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

and the `kb_nginx.conf` like so

```
# kb.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/kb.sock; # for a file socket
    #server 0.0.0.0:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name kenyabuzz.nation.news; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/static/kb/favicon.ico; # favicon
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

The log has:

```
2017/01/26 13:02:17 [crit] 4065#4065: *10 connect() to unix:///tmp/kb.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 197.232.12.165, server: kenyabuzz.nation.news, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/kb.sock:", host: "kenyabuzz.nation.news"
```

uwsgi should create the file automatically (it does) and it deletes it when it's closed using the example above.

Appreciate any help on this.

**UPDATE**

edited the .ini file and uncommented out the `chmod-socket=664` the kb.sock file is still not created on restarting nginx.

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to use sockets when you've explicitly told uwsgi to serve on an http port, ie port 8000.

Comment: I'm testing with the socket to make sure the site is configured correctly and serving via uwsgi. Now I setup nginx to serve with port 80 and check the domain and get the error mentioned. The additional socket test and port i.e. using `http :80` was trying to figure out if there's possibly a likelyhood that port 80 isn't working/available.

Comment: So please show the command you are actually using to start uwsgi.

Answer (score 1):

For nginx:

```
# kb.conf
...
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:/tmp/kb.sock;
}
...
```

For uWSGI:

```
# kb_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]
...
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /tmp/kb.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
...
```

Comment: tried this the log now indicates `2017/01/27 07:23:04 [error] 8639#8639: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/kb.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 197.232.12.165, server: kenyabuzz.nation.news, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/kb.sock:", host: "kenyabuzz.nation.news"`

Comment: I think I need to edit listen to either 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1:8000 or 80

Comment: switched to listen `0.0.0.0:80` static loads but the error log is the same.

Comment: What's in your `/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/uwsgi_params`?